# Show the Results of a SQL Query in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, reports, sql-query

I need to display the results of a SQL query within SharePoint 2013. I have written the query, which is saved as a view within SSMS however can't see an obvious way to simply display the results, formatted as a table, within SharePoint.

I appreciate that I will need to define data connections to the SQL Server instance, however once that is in place I can't see an obvious way of adding the results.

I would appreciate any advice on how to achieve this - should I be using Reporting Services or can this be done natively within SharePoint with a web part (I assume that it can)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Business Connectivity Services to gather the data from SQL-Server. You can check the following link for detailed inforamtion about BCS:
[Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj163782(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it took a while as authentication wasn't working but once that was fixed your link sent me in the right direction.